# JAVA - simple arithmetic with decimal places

Tags: java, decimal

people

How come this simple code yield different results?

```
System.out.println(1000.0/3.0/2.0/4.0/7.0);
System.out.println((double)(1000/3/2/4/7));
```

the output:

```
5.9523809523809526
5.0
```

And how can one perform such a simple arithmetic without casting every single member.

Extra: why does the following piece of code results in "int out of range error", even when I cast it?

```
long n1 = 291328282135; //Error description: The literal 291328282135 of type int is out of range.

//version with cast:
long n2 = (long) 291328282135; //Error description: The literal 291328282135 of type int is out of range.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Extra:" ask one question at a time.

Comment: A standalone sequence of digits is a 32-bit signed int in Java, so your second line of code does integer math and your ‘extra’ code is defining a number too large to fit in 32 bits.